# SQLite3_exec callback not called with INSERT statement in c++

Tags: c++, sqlite

My goal is to insert a column into a SQLite Table and then return the entry so that I can get the primary key value. I have the following code that executes generic insert statements for me:

```
 int SQLiteHelper::ExecuteWriteStatement(Platform::String^ statement)
 {
    char* zErrMsg;
int rc;

LPCWSTR input = statement->Data();
char sql[MAX_PATH + 1];
memset(sql, 0, sizeof(sql));
WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, input, -1, sql, sizeof(sql), NULL, NULL);

const char* data = "Callback function called";

rc = sqlite3_exec(m_db, sql, WriteCallback, (void*)data, &zErrMsg);

if(rc != SQLITE_OK)
{
    OutputDebugString(L"Failed to Write to database");
    sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
}
else
{
    OutputDebugString(L"Succesfully wrote to database");
}
 }
```

My callback is implemented as follows (note that it is a static private class method):

```
int SQLiteHelper::WriteCallback(void *NotUsed, int argc, char** argv, char** azColName)
{
   ////do some stuff
}
```

I am aware that I will probably use the `void* NotUsed` callback parameter to return data and I'm pretty sure it maps to the `(void*)data` from the sqlite3_exec() function call. The problem I have is that when I run an insert statement, the code does not reach the callback function.

If you run an insert command using sqlite3_exec shouldn't it call the callback method?

Is there a different sqlite command I should be using?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sqlite3_exec` callback gets called if the statement returns some data.
This can happen only for `SELECT` and some `PRAGMA` statements.

To get the rowid of the inserted record, call [sqlite3_last_insert_rowid](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html).